# Transfer question from SO to E&R

Tags: support

I'd like to transfer my questions from Stackoverflow to E&R. I made some questions there that fit better here. How is the best way to do this?

Comment: The moderators on SO can easily do this for you now, you just have to flag and request migration to E&R, they will probably take the time to verify with the mods here the migration path is valid but it should be pretty easy to handle. Let me know when you are flagging them all and I will make sure I am online to support the questions from them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly for you Stack Overflow only has migration paths for graduated sites.

On top of that, I fear that the overlap with Stack Overflow isn't large enough to justify a migration path.

So, it's better to just ask the question here again. Duplication doesn't have to be a bad thing, especially when the communities are so different.

Comment: Thank you for the expert advice.

Comment: You think it's better to inform that I have made the same question there? And what about the answers? Can I use some of them to answer new question here?

Comment: You can leave a comment emphasizing they you created another version here